# .NET reflector + Reflexil Plugin

Tags: plugins, .net-assembly, disassembly, reflexil

I've just installed reflexil v2.0 plugin but when I click on it after highliting a method it only displays 3 sub menus : Delete, Rename, Update Reflector object model...I'm not seeing Save as, Inject menus..anybody who can help me solve this?

Answer (score 5):

1) Install Reflector
2) download reflexil into Reflector\Addins folder

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Red Gate.NET Reflector\Desktop 9.0\Addins

3) open reflector > Tools > Add-Ins
4) add

> Reflexil.Reflector.dll

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Right click your assembly in left pane, choose ->reflexil->Save as

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XaWtoCmOGpw